# In Java, what is the advantage of declaring and initializing a java.util.(ex. list) in the body of the class as opposed to just importing is first?

Tags: java

For example,

```
public final static java.util.List VALUES = 
  Collections.unmodifiableList( 
    Arrays.asList( new Suit[] { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES } ) );
```

confused me in the way that it was written.  I'm so used to seeing java.util being imported.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

There's no benefit in doing that unless you've got *another* `List` class which is already being imported. Perhaps that's the case here?

Comment: I find it easier when generating code to just write out the qualified name and skip the imports.  With imports my code generator would have to write the imports, make sure there is no conflicts, and then write the simple names where appropriate.  None of this is impossible, but it is just easier to write out the qualified name.

Comment: @emory: Yes, for code generation it makes sense - but then I'd do it *uniformly*, so for Collections and Arrays as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will be more readable if you do the import, specially when you are using multiple times the same class.

I think **this** is more readable:

```
import java.util.List;

class A {
    List l1;
    List l2;
}
```

Than **this**:

```
class A {
    java.util.List l1;
    java.util.List l2;
}
```

Things will get even more clean when you start using **generics** on some declarations.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference.  There might be a "best practice" somewhere which states that you should import as opposed to giving fully namespaced classes where possible (or maybe the other way around).

Using the full namespace as opposed to just doing an import becomes useful when you start using 3rd party libraries together.  Say, for example you had a library to parse a csv and another to build an xml (building csv to xml).  Both libraries might declare a class called "Parser".  If you import them both, the compiler won't be able to tell which "Parser" class you're referring to, so that is a situation where you would want to use the full namespace as opposed to simply importing.